# Problema ao salvar resultado de uma query SQL em uma variável PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um `SELECT` para retornar o valor de um campo da tabela `funcionarionew`, minha ideia é salvar a o resultado do `SELECT` em uma variável e depois inserir o valor dessa variável em outra tabela (`terminal_cartao`).

No meu código, a variável `$cod` tem sempre valor `0`, o que não está correto. Qual será o problema?

```
include('connectdb.php');

$cli = $_POST['cliente'];
$car = $_POST['descricao'];
$loc = $_POST['local'];
$vend = $_POST['codigoVend'];

$sqlcode = mysql_query("UPDATE terminal_cartao SET cliente='$cli', local='$loc' WHERE descricao='$car'");

$sql="SELECT codigo FROM funcionarionew WHERE nome='$vend'";

while($ex=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$cod=$ex['codigo'];
}

$sqlcode1 = mysql_query("UPDATE terminal_cartao SET vendedor='$cod' WHERE descricao='$car'");
```

Comment: uma duvida teu $vend é um codigo ou nome ? vi que está pegando $_POST['codigoVend'] ?

Comment: @LucianoAzevedo é um nome, string

Comment: Já tentou executar esse sql direto no banco ? retornou ? verificou se o $_POST nao está vindo null ? pq whille ?

Comment: Mas não está fazendo a query do $SQL

Comment: Executando direto no banco está "ok", o $_POST também verifiquei, está correto.

Comment: como o @Daniel Gregatto falou, faltou o $sql = mysql_query("SELECT codigo....")

Comment: Todo o erro por uma distração boba! o problema era que não coloquei mysql_query no $sql. :( Obrigado pessoal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se o código abaixo funciona:
Verifiquei que não está fazendo o query da SQL e também está percorrendo um array quando quer na verdade trazer apenas 1 registro.

```
include('connectdb.php');

$cli = $_POST['cliente'];
$car = $_POST['descricao'];
$loc = $_POST['local'];
$vend = $_POST['codigoVend'];

$sqlcode = mysql_query("UPDATE terminal_cartao SET cliente='$cli', local='$loc' WHERE descricao='$car'");

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT codigo FROM funcionarionew WHERE nome='$vend' LIMIT 1");
$sql = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$cod = $sql['codigo'];

$sqlcode1 = mysql_query("UPDATE terminal_cartao SET vendedor='$cod' WHERE descricao='$car'");
```

Comment: Todo o erro por uma distração boba! o problema era que não coloquei `mysql_query` no `$sql`. :(